# ASP.NET MVC changed a lot after ScottGu's blogging?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm reading ScottGu's blog about ASP.NET MVC, and found a lot of code cannot compile or doesn't work as expected.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/11/13/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-1.aspx
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx

So, did ASP.NET MVC go through huge change after his blogging？
any up-to-date online tutorial about ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code is based on asp.net mvc 1.0 Preview2. Version 1 has been released, and Version 2 is currently in beta. Check out the samples at http://asp.net/mvc to get updated samples

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/

It HAS changed a lot, it was presented as a new beta version on PDC in LA in October...